# Valores duplicados al hacer una consulta entre 2 tablas en SQL

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una query entre la tabla `A(Orders)` y un `LEFT JOIN` con la tabla `D(Invoices)`.

Teniendo en cuenta que una **Orden** puede tener mas de una **Invoice**, se duplican las lineas.

En este caso, para la Orden 1001685349, se perpararon 2 facturas y algunos articulos aun no estan facturados. Es por ello que se abre en 3 lineas.

Lo que no entiendo es porque su duplica el valor de `SUM(A.ordered_quantity)`  en cada linea.

Las 2 lineas que contienen **Invoices** deberia darme la mitad del valor (2094 pero me esta dando 4188. Misma logica para la columna del Monto).

La ultima linea como no tiene **invoice**, me hace el SUM correctamente.

Imagino que debe ser algun tema con el `JOIN` pero no logro resolverlo.

¿Alguna sugerencia/idea?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Es necesario que expongas un escenario completo, con la consulta, y la salida, y lo que esperas que te devuelva. Además deberías de indicar en la etiqueta, que motor de base de datos usas, pues cada uno tiene un dialecto diferente.

Comment: Perdon, soy nuevo en la comunidad. Quise adjuntar captura para que se entienda y no salio. Ahi edite la pregunta. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es dificil entender el problema que tienes sin mas detalles adicionales, pero puedes intentar implementar un GROUP BY sobre tu consulta, de esta manera, todos los registros que se agrupen sobre un ID, o columnas similares, dejaran de duplicarse, para mas información acerca de como funciona el group by, te dejo en siguiente enlace https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-group-by/

Comment: Perdon, soy nuevo en la comunidad. Quise adjuntar captura para que se entienda y no salio.